# What is the field responsible for the synchrotron emission?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, synchrotron-radiation

Consider a usual synchrotron emission electron. What is the field responsible for its emission?

I know, for example, that the magnetic field that we have in the problem is not because magnetic fields do not do work. So, in the last instance, where does the radiation come from? Can I say that it is from the electric field that the particle itself generates? And if so, what are the physical arguments to justify it?

Answer (score 1):

An electron can be linearly accelerated by an electric potential. The electric field of the electron is attracted / retarded by the electric field of separated charges.

A moving electron can be deflected by a magnetic field (if the movement is not parallel to the field). The electrons magnetic dipole is aligned by the external magnetic field.

Any deflection is an acceleration and a lot of experiments have shown, that the electron radiates this time.

---

Too Long; Didn't Read

> So, in the last instance, where does the radiation come from?

The energy for the emission of EM radiation of a deflected electron has to come somewhere. And indeed it comes from the kinetic energy of the electron. The electron slows down and the real path is not a circle but a spiral.

Having a more close view its should be a spiral made from tangerine slices. each time of the emission of photons.

The inner mechanism has to do with the photon moment and with the perturbation of the electron's orientation. During emission, the magnetic dipole alignment of the electron is disturbed with the external field and this is the moment when the electron is deflected. These processes cycle many times until the electron has used up all its kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

The energy contained in synchrotron radiation comes from the kinetic energy of the electrons.

Without any means of maintaining their speed, the electrons would slow down as they emit synchrotron radiation. The force responsible for decelerating the electrons is known as a [radiation reaction force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force#:%7E:text=In%20the%20physics%20of%20electromagnetism,force%20or%20the%20self%2Dforce.). This arises from the momentum carried away by the synchrotron radiation and is not directly connected with the "external" magnetic field (which does no work, as you say).

Answer (score 0):

Radiation comes from bunches of charged particles that move together in accelerated motion (millions/ billions of particles can form single bunch). This EM radiation is the electric and magnetic field of those particles.

Its high strength far from the particles is explained by the assumption that fields of accelerated particles are the retarded solutions of the Maxwell equations (field of a particle at time $t$ and position $\mathbf x$ is a function of the retarded  position, velocity and acceleration of the charged particle). These retarded solutions behave as waves coming off the particle to all directions, with dipolar angular distribution of strength, and their amplitude falls off with distance $r$ as $1/r$. Radiation of these bunches carries EM energy away from the accelerator system.

This lost energy is repeatedly supplied by the accelerator in acceleration cavities: in the path there are special devices called acceleration cavities where electric field with the right oscillation pattern is produced to accelerate the charged particles. During this particles gain energy (both kinetic and electromagnetic) and then during their accelerated motion outside the cavity they lose it via radiation.